# Why does Application.Current == null in a WinForms application?

Tags: c#, winforms

Why does `Application.Current` come out to null in a WinForms application? How and when is it supposed to be set?

I am doing:

```
 static class Program {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main() {
            Application.Run(new MainForm());
        }
    }
```

Comment: There is no `System.Windows.Forms.Application.Current` property. Are you mixing with WPF?

Comment: This is the background for this question and I am trying to implement the solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35901454/how-to-raise-onpropertychanged-on-a-gui-thread-when-an-object-property-is-modifi

Comment: The only answer in the linked question I see starts with *for **WPF***.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Application.Current in ElementHost is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12198244/application-current-in-elementhost-is-null)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Application.Current is Specific for WPF Application.
Therefore when you are using WPF controls in WinForms Application you need to initialize instance of WPF Application. Do this in your WinForms Application.

```
if ( null == System.Windows.Application.Current )
{
   new System.Windows.Application();
}
```

Comment: Been a while since I've seen a Yoda Condition in C#.

Comment: This looks like it shouldn't work, but it does! Looking at the reference source [link](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Application.cs,695cdb0677ca5996) there is a static field _appInstance which is set upon the first time the constructor is called.

Answer (score 1):

Well IMHO opinion the other SO answer is not really the way to go for windows forms, although *maybe* not incorrect.

Normally you would use `ISynchronizeInvoke` for such a feature in WinForms. Every container control implements this interface.

You'll need to [`BeginInvoke()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.isynchronizeinvoke.begininvoke(v=vs.110).aspx) method to marshall the call back to the proper thread.

Based on your previous question the code would become:

```
public class SomeObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private readonly ISynchronizeInvoke invoker;
    public SomeObject(ISynchronizeInvoke invoker)
    {
        this.invoker = invoker;
    }

    public decimal AlertLevel
    {
        get { return alertLevel; }
        set
        {
            if (alertLevel == value) return;
            alertLevel = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("AlertLevel");
        }
    }

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            this.invoker.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName))), null);

        }
    }
}
```

Where you pass the owning `Form` class to the constructor of `SomeObject`. The PropertyChanged will now raised on the UI thread of the owning form class.

Answer (score 0):

Based on this other SO question, Application.Current is a WPF feature and not a WinForm feature: [Application.Current in ElementHost is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12198244/application-current-in-elementhost-is-null)

There is an [MSDN post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/30da10ad-865b-4b20-a6b8-6b73f994169c/applicationcurrent-does-not-exist?forum=csharplanguage) that shows how to leverage the feature in Winform by adding some references to your code:

you can add a reference to PresentationFramework first:

1.In Solution Explorer, right-click the project node and click Add Reference.

2.In the Add Reference dialog box, select the .NET tab.

3.Select the PresentationFramework, and then click OK.

4.Add "using System.Windows.Shell;" and "using System.Windows;" to your code.