# URI prefix is not recognized when setting the source of a resourcedictionary

Tags: c#, wpf, uri, resourcedictionary

> The URI prefix is not recognized

I am getting the above error message in a `System.NotSupportedException`.

This line is used to set the source of a `ResourceDictionary`:

```
view.Source = new Uri("/DA.EasyTeach.Math;component/View.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
```

This is a snip of my file structure:
[image]

**View.xaml** has a **Build Action** of *Resource*.

Comment: Try `new Uri("pack://application:,,,/DA.EasyTeach.Math;component/View.xaml")` without UriKind. See [Resource File Pack URIs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069(v=vs.100).aspx#Resource_File_Pack_URIs___Local_Assembly). Also make sure that `DA.EasyTeach.Math` is an assembly name, not a namespace.

Comment: Still getting the same error

Comment: @Clemens It's a `ResourceDictionary`, not `Frame`. `View.xaml` contains a `DataTemplate`.

Answer (score 6):

I have a hybrid application WinForms + WPF and the cause was `System.Windows.Application.Current == null`. Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35902815/why-does-application-current-null-in-a-winforms-application) I solved it by running following line before creating dictionary Uri:

```cs
new System.Windows.Application();
```

Answer (score 0):

I  finally discovered that the issue was not about the Uri. The `ResourceDictionary` was part of a plugin for a [MEF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460648(v=vs.110).aspx) application. I only had to merge the `ResourceDictionary` with the resources in the host. Solved!

I'm only putting this as an answer since it could help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Probably it could happen when you use multi-windowed application.

So in such case the possible solution can be to set Application shutdown mode:

```cs
public AppConstuctor()
{
    ShutdownMode = ShutdownMode.OnExplicitShutdown;
}
```

or in xaml:

```xml
<Application ...
             ShutdownMode="OnExplicitShutdown">
...
</Application>
```