# Application.Current and App.Current is null

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm creating an application (an Office Add-in for Outlook)

The issue I have is updating my screen. I know I need to use invoke the Dispatcher but, it's always null in my `ViewModel`

```
    private ObservableCollection<string> _updates;
    public ObservableCollection<string> Updates
    {
        get { return this._updates; }
        set
        {
            this._updates = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Updates");
        }
    }


        BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
        bw.DoWork += ((s, e) =>
        {
            //logic
            UpdateProgress("Finished");
        });

        bw.RunWorkerAsync();


    private void UpdateProgress(string s)
    {
        //Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
       // {
        App.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
        {            
            this.Updates.Add(s);
        //});
        });
    }
```

As you can see, I've tried 2 approaches, but `Current` is always null.

Oddly, if I use the same code in the code behind of my MainWindow then the following works fine

```
    private void UpdateProgress(string s)
    {
        Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
        {
            this.Update = s;
        });
    }
```

I've read up, the reason is because the MainWindow code behind inherits from Window.

My question is, do I have to create a new Dispatcher object or is there something I'm missing. All I'm trying to do is update my GUI whilst the thread is running.

Comment: Application.Current should be null if you attempt to access it in a non-UI thread. You can save a reference to dispatcher in constructor as a field member then use it in a non-UI thread.

Comment: The normal entrypoint for a WPF is Main().  Which is auto-generated to create your App.xaml class instance, hard to see.  The entrypoint is no longer Main() in an add-in, it is now you Startup event handler.  So you have to create your app instance yourself.  Boilerplate code [is here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2694710/17034).

Comment: @HansPassant, is there any way you can move this comment to an answer?

Comment: Just type up the answer in your own post, show what your Startup event handler looks like, and mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answered in comments by Hans Passant

> The normal entrypoint for a WPF is Main(). Which is auto-generated to create your App.xaml class instance, hard to see. The entrypoint is no longer Main() in an add-in, it is now you Startup event handler. So you have to create your app instance yourself. Boilerplate code is http://stackoverflow.com/a/2694710/17034

[Application.Current and App.Current is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39644256/application-current-and-app-current-is-null/50798025#comment66593423_39644256)

Answer (score 2):

As a workaround you could maybe do the following:

```
public MainWindow()
{
  InitializeComponent();
  AppWindow = this; // Here you set the static member to reference this MainWindow.
}

public static MainWindow AppWindow
{
  get;
  private set;
}
```

And then in your viewmodel:

```
private void UpdateProgress(string s)
{
  MainWindow.AppWindow.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
  {
    this.Updates.Add(s);
    //});
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to open a WPF application from a Winforms appliation, Application.Current is null. Application.Current is a feature of WPF applications only and not Winforms. You may try the below link:

[Why does Application.Current == null in a WinForms application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35902815/why-does-application-current-null-in-a-winforms-application)

Comment: Don't ignore tags, winforms != wpf. Also on SO we are closing questions as duplicates rather than creating new answers with link to duplicated questions.

Comment: You need to read the reply completely. I was trying to to help this person from something I had earlier faced; and it was in WPF, since I was creating a WPF window from another Winforms app. Don't be keen to just down vote. Also, as far as closing is concerned, not everyone can close a question. You have the required points, hence you are able to.