# SingleInstanceApp with External command line args in Winforms

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms

I am familiar with WPF application but completely new to Winforms.

The objective is to create a single instance Winforms application.  If another instance instantiated, it should notify the main instance with corresponding command args that will invoke action on main instance.  Here is the [sample](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/84270/WPF-Single-Instance-Application) that will work on WPF.

I have achieved the same in WPF using the [MSDN helper](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/arik/SingleInstance.cs.txt). But when I try to make use of the same in Winforms, I could not resolve the following things.

- `Application` instance missing in Winforms.
- `Application.Current`is missing that will be used to invoke the main instance.

Is there any equivalent in winforms, or any other way to achieve the similar functionality in Winforms.

Comment: please refer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35902815/why-does-application-current-null-in-a-winforms-application

Comment: Look into [`mutex` at MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_7)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is to use a `Mutex` to detect an instance is already running. To communicate with the first instance, you can use IPC (inter process communication). Here's the code:

```
static class Program
{
    const string AppId = "Local\\1DDFB948-19F1-417C-903D-BE05335DB8A4"; // Unique par application 

    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var mutex = new Mutex(false, AppId))
        {
            if (!mutex.WaitOne(0))
            {
                // 2nd instance
                // Send the command line to the first instance
                IpcChannel clientChannel = new IpcChannel();
                ChannelServices.RegisterChannel(clientChannel, false);
                SingleInstance app = (SingleInstance)Activator.GetObject(typeof(SingleInstance), string.Format("ipc://{0}/RemotingServer", AppId));
                app.Execute(args);
                return;
            }

            // 1st instance

            // Register the IPC server
            IpcChannel channel = new IpcChannel(AppId);
            ChannelServices.RegisterChannel(channel, false);
            RemotingConfiguration.RegisterWellKnownServiceType(typeof(SingleInstance), "RemotingServer", WellKnownObjectMode.Singleton);

            // Start the application
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
    }

    private class SingleInstance : MarshalByRefObject
    {
        public void Execute(string[] args)
        {
            // TODO use the args sent by the second instance
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect answer!  Thanks a lot... Really helped me.

Answer (score 0):

Documentation on MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f55ddskf(v=vs.110).aspx

## Short how-to

- In the startup of the application, create/open a Mutex with a unique name (it's scope is global/system

`var mutex = new Mutex(false, "My awesome single-instance project");`

- Check if the Mutex is already taken/controlleed

`var isMutexControlled = mutex.WaitOne(0, false);`

- If it is already controlled, exit the application.

For more in-depth, community knowledge, look at this answer which provides a robust way to create a Mutex: [What is a good pattern for using a Global Mutex in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/229565/what-is-a-good-pattern-for-using-a-global-mutex-in-c?noredirect=1&lq=1)

#### Bonus Q&A

Q: Why is Application or Application.Current not available or null?

A: It is a [System.Windows.Application.Current](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.current%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is *only* found in the WPF libraries, not in the Windows Forms libraries. They are separate frameworks of building a visual application (though they can be combined but let's not go down that rabbit hole).

Answer (score 0):

You could use a global Mutex like this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1213517

Or use a Windows event like in this answer :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/646500