# Dispatcher.Invoke throws NullReference exception

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, dispatcher

I have a WPF `UserControl` that is being tested in both a `WPF` app and `WinForms` app. The control is made up of other controls, mainly a map control. Work is done inside the `UserControl` using `Tasks` and doing work on the map control by using `Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke`.

Everything works fine when hosting this control in a WPF app, but in the `WinForms` app, a NullReference exception is thrown anytime the `Dispatcher.Invoke` is used. In fact, `Application.Current` is always null in the WinForms app.

I've seen this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14753962/2480598 which suggests:

```
if ( null == System.Windows.Application.Current )
{
   new System.Windows.Application();
}
```

But what if I don't have control over the `WinForms` app? Is there no other way to handle this?

Comment: Have a look at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/303116/system-windows-threading-dispatcher-and-winforms) as well. You can try to use `Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher`

Comment: The `DispatcherObject` base class has a `Dispatcher` property. Try to use this one instead of `Application.Current.Dispatcher`.

Comment: Thank you to both. Using the `Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher` seemed to do the trick.